# win 11 and bash to execute conda and python

Tags: windows, bash

i want to create a .Bat in order to execute conda env and run python app. But there is a problem with my bash. I run it and the windows automaticaly close. thanks for your help

```
@echo off
conda activate facefusion
cd /d d:\GITHUB\Facefusion\
python run.py -o C:\Users\ryzen\Videos --keep-fps --max-memory MAX_MEMORY --execution-providers cuda --execution-queue-count 10 --frame-processors face_swapper face_enhancer

pause
```